# IShellItem2.GetString returning E_NOTFOUND for PKEY_Devices_Status1 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, com, windows-shell

#### Problem

[`IShellItem2.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761127.aspx) returns E_NOTFOUND for [`PKEY_Devices_Status1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391641.aspx) and [`PKEY_Devices_Status2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391642.aspx) for all devices on Windows 7 (build 6.1.7601). This is unexpected because they were introduced in Windows 7 and they work in Windows 10.

I’m showing a list of printers by enumerating the shell items in [`Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741(v=vs.85).aspx#DevicesAndPrinters), checking the [`PKEY_Devices_CategoryIds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt805664.aspx), and showing the icon and [`PKEY_Devices_FriendlyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391610.aspx), [`PKEY_Devices_Status1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391641.aspx), and [`PKEY_Devices_Status2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391642.aspx). All of these list Windows 7 as their lowest supported OS except `PKEY_Devices_CategoryIds` which lists only Windows 10 but works without a problem (and indeed is vital) on Windows 7.

Everything works on Windows 10, besides a random 0 to 200 ms delay where the status properties are not found which is easily solved by polling until they become available.

Trying to fake the status messages on Windows 7 by falling back on `GetPrinter` and `EnumJobs` is not a good solution because I’ll never be able to match Windows’ localization of the display string.

#### Images

These are the Windows 7 Devices and Printers status lines for which I expect to be able to get shell display strings, but there seems to be no way to access them:

[image]

These are the Windows 10 Devices and Printers status lines which are returned as expected by `PKEY_Devices_Status1` and `PKEY_Devices_Status2`:

[image]

#### Summary

I’m lost as to how to troubleshoot further. Am I accessing the shell item properties the wrong way? Do I need a magic flag somewhere? Is this an impossible task on Windows 7?